# iOS face tracking while detection with CIDetector

Tags: ios, face-detection

Here is the actual problem: During face detection in streamed video I need to track which faces where detected in previous iterations and which are new one. This could be possibly done with

CIFaceFeature trackingID

property, but here comes the hard part. 
First of all: CIDetector returns array of

CIFaceFeatureInternal

objects instead of CIFaceFeature. They are almost like CIFaceFeature, but doesn't contain any tracking id or eyes data.
Currently I tried it on iOS 5, so as

CIDetectorTracking

option for CIDetector is available only from iOS 6 maybe thats something expected. Anyway, I need to target iOS 5 in my application. I could possibly try to determine if some face is still present on screen by calculating detected faces rectangles, but without additional information like eyes and mouth position that will be very uncertain.

So here comes the question:

How can I detect faces from video output in iOS 5 and also get some tracking id for found faces?

If I can get a direction at least, maybe some 3rd party library like openCV or some explanation that would be very helpful.